# Why is the Sprite's graphics object not drawing to the screen?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, actionscript-3

When I debug my code nothing appears on screen. I've rechecked the code and consulted with others yet nothing appears. My html template is fine.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class asgnv2 extends Sprite
    { 
        var lineY = 0;
        public function asgnv2()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            graphics.lineStyle(1);
        }
        function update(e){
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.moveTo(0 ,lineY);
            graphics.lineTo(100, lineY);
            lineY+=0.5;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you referencing asgnv2? In other words, how do you use asgnv2 so that it is expected to appear on the stage?

Answer (score 1):

unless `asgnv2` is Document class, it is not going to work, as you are registering ENTER_FRAME event on the stage inside the constructor of asgnv2. A DisplayObject can not access stage property until it is added to Stage Display List. So try the following.

```
public function asgnv2(){
  this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
  graphics.lineStyle(1);
}
```

private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
  this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
}
private function update(e:Event):void{
  //do the stuff
}